# How do I setup android sdk for android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I recently downloaded android studio and flutter. I have the flutter plugin and the dart plugin but the android sdk is not configured and I dont know how to configure it.

Things I already did:

- Install Flutter Plugin
- Install Dart plugin
- Selected a sdk (under project structure)
- asked chat gpt
- ran flutter doctor
  [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
  X cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
  X Android license status unknown.
  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
- followed the steps flutter doctor provided (nothing happened)
- followed tutorials on yt (most of them were older so i didnt have most of the options shown in the videos)
- tried to download several sdks

I'm relatively new to programming with flutter and dart and using android studio so I have no idea what to do. I tried almost everything i found on the internet but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Have you added android sdk to your PATH variable?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting is releted to cmdline-tool component. This component is required for Flutter.

To install the cmdline tool follow the steps:

1. In menu bar click **Tool>SDK Manager**
2. In the SDK Platform tab, select **Android 14**
3. In the SDK Tool tag, select **Android SDK Command-line Tools**
4. And Click **OK**

Once the SDK has been installed, you should be able to run the command to accept the SDK licenses.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

[image: See Attachment]